# Jquery identifying data attribute in for each loop

Tags: jquery, foreach, custom-data-attribute

I am looking through some elements that have the same class and making an AJAX call, depending on the returned value I want to change the img src, attribute.  But use the data attribute to identify the correct object?

```
 $("button.checkStatus").click(function(){
        //This Ajax checks the current on/off status of the passed X10 code
        $('.checkStatus').each(function(i, obj) {
            $x10Device = $(this).data("x10");
            //var data = "url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=C5" //& $x10Device ; //this is passed in the device toggle

        var data = "url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=" + $x10Device ; //this is passed in the device toggle

        $.ajax({                  
              url:"urlencode.php",
              data: data,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) { 
                  myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
                  var Nmyd = myd.charAt(3);
                  if (Nmyd == '2'){$('img').attr('src','lightbulbon.png')}else{$('img').attr('src','lightbulboff.png')};    
                  },
              error: function (request, status, error) 
               {   
                alert(request.responseText);
                }
     });
     });
     });
```

Comment: Your data variable doesn't what you expect, it's unclear where the url parameter ends and the next one begins. I suggest building it as an object, then passing it as an object to ajax. jQuery will then pass it to `$.param`

Comment: The if statement is where I am having a problem I don't how to write it so it checks the data attribute against $x10Device.  If $x10Device = "C5" then I only want to alter this element.  As it stands it replaces all img tags.